# permanent app position on multi monitor setup

Tags: windows-7, multiple-monitors

I am currently using a 22" monitor with my 12" laptop docked to its station. Every time I start up or throughout the course of usage, I would like to have Evernote maximized and permanently docked to the 12" display, instead of manually dragging it myself every single instance.

How can this be achieved? Thank you.